# MPTweakValue without internet

Tags: ios, mixpanel, tweak

I try to implement Mixpanel's tweaks into my app for A/B testing. This is my code:

```
if (MPTweakValue(kFeaturedOffersTweak, NO)) {
    return MenuItemRowHeight;
}
else {
    return 0;
}
```

On the first lunch everything is OK and tweak value is YES. Then I switch off internet on my iPhone, open run again and tweak value is NO.

What is correct way to use Mixpanel's tweak without internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I created my custom manager, where I implemented tweaks' persistency.
Please, let me know, if you have better solution.

My code:

```
-(void)initManager {
    [[Mixpanel sharedInstance] joinExperimentsWithCallback:^{

        USE_SETTINGS;

        SETTINGS_SETBOOL(kPreferredPartnersTweak, MPTweakValue(kPreferredPartnersTweak, NO));

        SYNCHRONIZE_SETTINGS;

        //===

        SEND_NOTIF(kTweaksUpdated, nil);
    }];
}

-(BOOL)getTweakWithName:(NSString*)tweakName {

    BOOL result = NO;

    //===

    USE_SETTINGS;

    if (SETTINGS_BOOL(tweakName)) {

        result = SETTINGS_BOOL(tweakName);
    }
    else {
        result = MPTweakValue(kPreferredPartnersTweak, NO);
    }

    //===

    return result;
}
```

`USE_SETTINGS`, `SETTINGS_BOOL`, `SYNCHRONIZE_SETTINGS` is my macros wrappers for working with `NSUserDefaults`.